# Spring RestTemplate gives 401 Authorization Required while getting data from Twitter

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I am trying to get twitter tweets using Spring RestTemplate. My code is below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders();

    String url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json q=java";        
    String headerName = "Authorization";
    String headerValue = OAUTH_PARAMETERS
    httpHeaders.add(headerName, headerValue);
    httpHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>("Headers", httpHeaders);
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>" + restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class).getBody());
}
```

I am getting following errors:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401
>   Authorization Required    at
>   org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:475)
>     at
>   com.lftechnology.amlf.screening.service.impl.BalanceMediaSearchResultServiceImpl.main(BalanceMediaSearchResultServiceImpl.java:202)

Comment: Please let us know if the answer below fixed your issue.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that you are setting wrong parameters in the header. Try this:

```
httpHeaders.set("Authorization","Bearer " + accessToken);
```

notice that the space after Bearer is important.